# How to unable to switch login domain? directory domain?

Tags: boot, 18.04, login, directory, home-directory

My company mostly uses Windows and I am one of the very few who needs Linux; it means that the IT unit does not know much about it! They installed the Ubuntu for me with an active directory enabled to have access to the network folders. However, they made a mistake and created two different parent directories (to be honest I am not sure whether the term I used is correct), one `fe` and another one `FE`. Please check the screenshot
[image: screenshot of home directory]

I have installed whatever I need on the `FE` domain, but once in a while, when I restart and login it enters `fe` domain, which I have nothing installed. I even deleted `fe` directory whenever I am in `FE` domain. However, I am now logged out my domain and whatever I do it just keeps entering `fe` domain. When I sign in, it says:

> creating /home/fe/ ...

anyone has any idea how I can get rid of this problem?

Comment: Could you move everything from `FE` to `fe`, then remove `FE`, and create a symbolic link from `FE` to `fe`? This should work unless there is stuff in `FE` with the same name as stuff in `fe` and you need both.

Comment: @semaran those seem to be different users, not AD domains. Your company's IT department is most likely not going to be happy if you try to solve this problem yourself, especially if that involves deleting users and their home directories. I'd suggest you get in touch with them first. Maybe the two users weren't even a mistake in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @Jos. I don't need anything in fe domain, however, I have too many files and packages installed in FE. I am afraid such movement will cause problem to some of them. Isn't there any way that allows me to login to FE?

Comment: @denzel I have already talked to them. It was a mistake. By the way, none of them is user. The directory of the users are actually sub-directory of fe and FE; for instance, my directory is FE/username...

Comment: If you don't need anything in the `fe` domain but have `FE` as your standard home directory, do it the other way around: delete `fe` and create a symbolic link from `fe` to `FE`.

Comment: @Jos that sounds good. Since I have never done such a thing, I gonna about a couple of details. Could you be more specific? The symbolic link should be from a particular config file in fe to FE? or how exactly? sorry for too many questions...

Comment: @Jos I managed to do it the way you suggested. But it does not log in anymore. On the login screen I also tried logging in in tty2 (i.e., pushing ALT+Shift+F2), but it logs in and comes back to the login page promptly...

Comment: The link should be created like this: `sudo ln -s /home/FE /home/fe` after you have deleted `/home/fe`.

Comment: @Jos, I did exactly like what you said. However, I can no longer log in to my Linux. It is locked in a login loop!

Comment: It did work now! Thanks @Jos.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Jos was right and it solved my problem. Here is the solution:

I don't need anything in the fe domain but have FE as my standard home directory. I delete fe and create a symbolic link from fe to FE. The link should be created like this:

```
sudo ln -s /home/FE /home/fe
```

after you have deleted `/home/fe`.